# How to fix Uncaught Syntax Error when I run react project with node

Tags: reactjs

I am building one react project, it is working well in my local before I build it.
But after build, I tried to integrate with node backend, but it shows me these errors.

[image]

This is my backend code. I already build my react front project.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// Middleware for parsing requests bodies.
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../build');

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
  const result = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    message: req.body.message
  };

  let mailContent = `<html><div>I would like to meet you</div><div style='display:flex'><div>User Name:</div><div> ${result.name}</div></div><div style='display:flex'><div>User email:</div><div>${result.email}</div></div><div style='display:flex'><div>Message:</div><div>${result.message}</div></div></html>`;

  let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
      pass: 'xxxx'
    }
  });

  let mailDetails = {
    from: result.email,
    to: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    subject: result.subject,
    html: mailContent
  };

  mailTransporter.sendMail(mailDetails, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error Occurs');
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent successfully');
    }
  });
  res.send();
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Server is running at ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: please add you bundling scripts. Are you using create react app or a custom setup to build you react project?

Comment: Thank you so much.
I am using minimal theme for my project.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are seeing are related to the presence of `<` tokens in your final code. So it is not a node problem.

Usually this kind of errors are caused by a missing compilation phase from Babel, where your JSX code is compiled into calls to `React.createElement`.

You can try to add Babel directly in your index.html file directly. Add inside your `<head></head>` section this script:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

To fix your build, you need to post more details from your project's setup.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response. Can you tell me how to fix this issue in my project?

Comment: Which information do you need? I inseted your code in my build/index.html/ <head>
But issue is same

Comment: ok, I am using minimal.cc theme, I am customizing it, If you want, I will show you my full source code.